# Scraping the web in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm completely new to scraping the web but I really want to learn it in python. I have a basic understanding of python.

I'm having trouble understanding a code to scrape a webpage because I can't find a good documentation about the modules which the code uses.

The code scraps some movie's data of [this](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012) webpage

I get stuck after the comment "selection in pattern follows the rules of CSS".

I would like to understand the logic behind that code or a good documentation to understand that modules. Is there any previous topic which I need to learn?

The code is the following :

```
import requests
from pattern import web
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.url

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title'
params = dict(sort='num_votes,desc', start=1, title_type='feature', year='1950,2012')
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print r.url  # notice it constructs the full url for you

#selection in pattern follows the rules of CSS

dom = web.Element(r.text)
for movie in dom.by_tag('td.title'):    
    title = movie.by_tag('a')[0].content
    genres = movie.by_tag('span.genre')[0].by_tag('a')
    genres = [g.content for g in genres]
    runtime = movie.by_tag('span.runtime')[0].content
    rating = movie.by_tag('span.value')[0].content
    print title, genres, runtime, rating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation for [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which is an HTML and XML parser.

The comment

> selection in pattern follows the rules of CSS

means the strings such as `'td.title'` and `'span.runtime'` are CSS selectors that help find the data you are looking for, where `td.title` searches for the `<TD>` element with attribute `class="title"`.

The code is iterating through the HTML elements in the webpage body and extracting title, genres, runtime, and rating by the CSS selectors .